# How to show a custom 500 page in nginx + vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, nginx

My project is a spa on vue.js, which runs on the nginx web server and which is located on the digital ocean droplet.
I had a need to show the user, instead of the default 500 error message, a custom page with a 500 error.
I found instructions on how to do this on the digitalocean website: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04,
but unfortunately this recipe does not work in my case.
Below is my nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-app-domain.io;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-my-app-cf.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/ssl-key-my-app-cf.pem;

    server_name my-app-domain.io;
    root        /var/www/my-app-domain.io/dist;
    index       index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    auth_basic           "Administrator's Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
    location = /custom_50x.html {
        ssi on;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index custom_50x.html
        internal;
    }

    location /testing {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/does/not/exist;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = my-app-domain.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    listen 80;
}
```

As a result, when I go to the / testing page, I expect to see a custom page of 500 errors, but I see this.
[image]

Comment: let your router redirect your SPA to the error page (component) when your http library detects any error for the http response.

Comment: @Sphinx I’ll explain my case in more detail: I use the practice of content delivery and when the build occurs on the server, I want to show the user a custom 500. If I make 500 through the routing of the component, this will not help me, since the application files will not be available during build and web server returns 500.

Answer (score 1):

your public files here

```
/var/www/my-app-domain.io/dist;
```

your need to change the 500 page the that directory

not in the default one

```
/usr/share/nginx/html;
```

exmple

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /error.html;

location = /error.html {
  ssi on;
  internal;
  auth_basic off;
  root /var/www/my-app-domain.io;
}
```

also if that not work u can use my config

```
            location / {

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  
        error_page 404 =  /index.php;
         error_page 403 /403.html;

        }

        error_page 404 =301 https://domain.io/;
        error_page 403 /403.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/html/live;


 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, unfortunately, during the build, the web server gives a default 500 page, instead of the specified one.

Comment: hey there can u share log files 
just type
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log